# JScrollPane prevents interaction with contents

Tags: java, swing, awt, jscrollpane

I have a `JScrollPane` whose client is a `Container` with layout `BoxLayout`.

Within the `BoxLayout` are multiple (dynamically generated) `JPanels`. However, the `JScrollPane` doesn't scroll (the scrollbars show and resize, but you can't actually move them), and I also can't interact with the contents of the `JScrollPane`.

Here's the code:

```
public static void setupOrderTable(){
        orderTable = new Container(); 
        scroller = new JScrollPane(orderTable ,ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(810,500));
        orderTable.setLayout(new BoxLayout(orderTable,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        if (orderTable!=null)
            mainContainer.remove(orderTable);
        for (Order o: OrderManager.getList()){
            orderTable.add(new ControlRowItem(o));
        }
        mainContainer.add(scroller,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
    }
```

It works fine if I just replace the line

```
mainContainer.add(scroller,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

with

```
mainContainer.add(orderTable,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

But then it obviously doesn't scroll. Otherwise, as I said, the scrollbars don't work and I can't interact with any of the JPanels within the orderTable.

[image: Here's a screenshot if that helps]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix heavy weight (`Container`) components with lightweight (`JScrollPane`) components, they just don't mix well.  Change `orderTable` to be a `JPanel` instead

While it's suppose to have been fixed in Java 6, I've seen too many weird things with trying this to make it worth any effort at all.  Simply rule, don't mix heavy weight components (AWT) in Swing containers

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This didn't solve my problem, but it's good to know. Do you think there could be a problem with threads? That's the only thing I can think of since threads always confuse me and seem to screw everything up (in terms of updating and making the UI stop responding) whenever I'm using Swing.

Comment: @LukeBaumann Have a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem? This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: *"I've seen too many weird things with trying this to make it worth any effort at all."*  Plus ten..